# Python - Tkinter - Scrollbar Very Slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Does anyone know why the xscrollbar on Tkinter is running so slow?

Below is a simple testcase:

```python
import tkinter as tk

content = ''
for x in range(40):
    content += str(x)*7000 + '\n'

window = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(wrap = tk.NONE)
text.insert(tk.INSERT, content)
text.pack()
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(window, orient = 'horizontal')
scrollbar.config(command = text.xview)
scrollbar.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM, fill = tk.X)
text.config(xscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling works fairly fast for me. I think the simple answer is "because you have a lot of very long strings". Having lines with either 7000 or 14000 characters is not the type of thing the text widget was optimized for.

Comment: The code runs faster, but when moving the scrollbar, the text refresh is so slow, I just created a simple test case, but I am having the same issue with real text data.